# Assign interfaced typed data to a class of default properties

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to assign an object of data typed from an interface of optional properties with nested interfaces with optional properties as well to a class / object with default values.

I have a collection of Interfaces, all with optional properties

```
export interface ICard {
  title?: string;
  date?: Date;
  style?: ICardStyle;
  body?: ICardContent;
  footer?: ICardFooter;
}

export interface ICardContent {
  content?: string;
  style?: ICardStyle;
}

export interface ICardFooter extends ICardContent {
  username?: string;
  url?: string;
}

export interface ICardStylePadding {
  top?: string;
  bottom?: string;
  left?: string;
  right?: string;
}

export interface ICardStyle {
  color?: string;
  background?: string;
  padding?: ICardStylePadding;
}
```

And for each of those interfaces, I have extended classes from them with default values.

```
export class CardContent implements ICardContent {
  content = 'Some dummy text';
  style = new CardStyle();
}

export class CardFooter implements ICardFooter {
  content = 'Some dummy text for footer';
  style = new CardStyle();
  username = 'Default User';
  url = 'https://example.com';
}

export class CardStyle implements ICardStyle {
  color = 'black';
  background = 'white';
  padding = new CardStylePadding();
}

export class CardStylePadding implements ICardStylePadding {
  top = '10px';
  bottom = '10px';
  left = '5px';
  right = '5px';
}
```

I'm doing this, so I don't have to evaluate each property of an object and nested objects when passing a value of `ICard`. I could suppress the linting errors, but I really don't want to. I'm trying to create a class from the data, which works fine at a top level, or If I don't change any properties of the child objects.

I have three functions I've tried

```
  // Works fine at the top level only
  public LoadConfig(config: ICard): void {
    this.Config = { ...new Card(), ...Object.assign(new Card(), config) };
  }

  // Works as intended but not really managable if the objects grow and change
  public LoadConfig2(config: ICard): void {
    const newConfig = new Card();

    if (config.title) {
      newConfig.title = config.title;
    }

    if (config.date) {
      newConfig.date = config.date;
    }

    if (config.body) {
      if (config.body.style) {
        newConfig.body.style = this.GenerateStyle(config.body.style);
      }
    }

    if (config.footer) {
      if (config.footer.style) {
        newConfig.footer.style = this.GenerateStyle(config.footer.style);
      }
      if (config.footer.content) {
        newConfig.footer.content = config.footer.content;
      }
      if (config.footer.url) {
        newConfig.footer.url = config.footer.url;
      }
      if (config.footer.username) {
        newConfig.footer.username = config.footer.url;
      }
    }

    if (config.style) {
      newConfig.style = this.GenerateStyle(config.style);
    }

    this.Config = newConfig;
  }

  private GenerateStyle(style: ICardStyle): CardStyle {
    const newStyle = new CardStyle();
    if (style.padding) {
      newStyle.padding = Object.assign(newStyle.padding, newStyle.padding);
    }
    if (style.background) {
      newStyle.background = newStyle.background;
    }
    if (style.color) {
      newStyle.color = newStyle.color;
    }

    return newStyle;
  }

  // Same problems as LoadConfig
  public LoadConfig3(config: ICard){
    this.Config = Object.assign(new Card(), Object.assign(new Card(), config));
  }
```

Is there a way to assign the data to the classes?

Attatched is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zsis7d?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: This is really not ideal indeed. You know classes can have constructors right? So the Object.assign could be done in the class itself.

Comment: Also - if you setup your classes with all possible props, you really don't need those interfaces. Classes itself act like interfaces as well.

Comment: @MikeOne I didn't even think about putting the `Object.assign` into the constructors for itself, I'll give that a try. The reason for the classes and interfaces, is to force the properties to not be undefined-able within the class. Every property should have a value, whether it's added or default, prevents putting in many conditionals to validate if there is a value or not to beat the linting. I could turn all the interface properties to non-optional but when passing in the configuration, the entire object would have to be constructed.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. You can also make class props optional if you want?

Comment: I'm passing data into a component (class), the data can be completely optional, This is where the interface comes in, all properties are set to optional. So, I could say `InitialiseComponent({})` and the component would use default values where they don't exist. When inside the component, I don't want to write, `if(config.property)`, which I would have to do with strict type checking and linting because the type of property is `type | undefined`. So extending the class to use the interface, I can define that properties type is only `type` - Sorry my explanation skills are weak, I am trying.

Comment: You don't have to apologise ;-) - I forked your stackblitz to show what I mean. I'm not using any interfaces, just a class. Not entirely sure this is what you need - but it is just to show what I mean: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hxoha2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I've forked your fork. Stackblitz by default doesn't have strict compiler option switched on, so I've switched that on, and on line 106 of `app.component.ts` you can see the problem with having the properties in the class as optional. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-simz2a?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Right - gotcha! But that really doesn't have anything to do with the interface versus class discussion. Your interfaces are still not really solving that right? If you choose to go strict, you have to be willing to do undefined checks all over the place (although you could make a generic type guard function for that?)

Comment: I updated my blitz (also in strict now).. there are some options there, but you need to type with undefined more. The title in the class (not initialized) you can change to title!: string; (with exclamation mark) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-khwml9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Regarding the classes vs interface discussion, the classes don't actually need to implement the interface as all the properties are optional, I could have a simple class that implements the same properties however the interface will allow the compiler to check for mismatched properties. For example, property title on the interface is optional, but on the class, property title is set to type string only, in the example because I'm assigning a default string value. So, when accessing the property from the class, I don't need to check the value for undefined.

Comment: If it works for you - it's all good!